# Different S3 behavior using different endpoints?

Tags: rest, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm currently writing code to use Amazon's S3 REST API and I notice different behavior where the only difference seems to be the Amazon endpoint URI that I use, e.g., `https://s3.amazonaws.com` vs. `https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com`.

Examples of different behavior for the the GET Bucket (List Objects) call:

- Using one endpoint, it *includes* the "folder" in the results, e.g.:

  ```
  /path/subfolder/
  /path/subfolder/file1.txt
  /path/subfolder/file2.txt
  ```

  and, using the other endpoint, it does ***not** include* the "folder" in the results:

  ```
  /path/subfolder/file1.txt
  /path/subfolder/file2.txt
  ```
- Using one endpoint, it represents "folders" using a trailing `/` as shown above and, using the other endpoint, it uses a trailing `_$folder$`:

  ```
  /path/subfolder_$folder$
  /path/subfolder/file1.txt
  /path/subfolder/file2.txt
  ```

Why the differences? How can I make it return results in a consistent manner regardless of endpoint?

Note that I get these same odd results even if I use Amazon's *own* command-line AWS S3 client, so it's *not* my code.

Comment: Sounds like a case for AWS support. If the files in the buckets are publicly available, could you add the bucket name to the question?

Comment: @l0b0 The buckets are not publicly available.

Comment: That is very strange, but I suspect there is a sensible, legacy-related explanation... but let's tighten the focus, somewhat, because you have not been specific about which region the buckets are in and which exact endpoints are providing which type of results.  You don't need to give us your bucket names, but how many buckets are involved, and which ones (bucket A, B, C, etc.) provide which behavior at which endpoint is information that we need.

Comment: I am also reasonably confident that either I am reading something into the question that you did not intend... or you have lost track of your observations and are in fact talking about different bucket behavior but that the endpoint is only different because you're looking at different buckets... created by different applications... and that for an given bucket, the behavior doesn't change across endpoints.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot I've mirrored the bucket "folder" layout exactly. And the contents of the buckets should be irrelevant anyway. Either the GET Bucket REST call should return the sub"folder" or it shouldn't. If you choose not to believe that the behavior I'm seeing is in fact as I describe, well, nothing I can do about that.

Comment: I did not say you were not seeing it; however, I don't believe you're seeing it on multiple endpoints for the same bucket, which is what your question implies.  You're working with two buckets, in two different regions, and you've assume it has something to do with the endpoints, when in fact it is about how the content in the buckets was created.

Answer (score 1):

> *And the contents of the buckets should be irrelevant anyway.*

Your assertion notwithstanding, your issue is *exactly* about the *content* of the buckets, and not something S3 is doing -- the S3 API has no concept of folders.  None.  The S3 *console* can display folders, but this is for convenience -- the folders are not really there -- or if there are folder-like entities, they're irrelevant and not needed.

> In Amazon S3, buckets and objects are the primary resources, where objects are stored in buckets. Amazon S3 has a flat structure with no hierarchy like you would see in a typical file system. However, for the sake of organizational simplicity, the Amazon S3 console supports the folder concept as a means of grouping objects. Amazon S3 does this by using key name prefixes for objects.
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

**So why are you seeing this?**

Either you've been using EMR/Hadoop, or some other code written by someone who took a bad example and ran with it... or is doing something differently than it should have been done for quite some time.

> Amazon EMR is a web service that uses a managed Hadoop framework to process, distribute, and interact with data in AWS data stores, including Amazon S3. Because S3 uses a key-value pair storage system, the Hadoop file system implements directory support in S3 by creating empty files with the `<directoryname>_$folder$` suffix.
>
> https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/emr-s3-empty-files/

This may have been something the S3 console did many years ago, and apparently (since you don't report seeing them in the console) it still supports displaying such objects as folders in the console... but the S3 console no longer creates them this way, if it ever did.

> *I've mirrored the bucket "folder" layout exactly*

If you create a folder in the console, an empty object with the key "foldername/" is created.  This in turn is used to display a folder that you can navigate into, and upload objects with keys beginning with that folder name as a prefix.

> The Amazon S3 console treats all objects that have a forward slash "/" character as the last (trailing) character in the key name as a folder
>
> http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/UG/FolderOperations.html

If you just create objects using the API, then "my/object.txt" appears in the console as "object.txt" inside folder "my" even though there is no "my/" object created... so if the objects are created with the API, you'd see neither style of "folder" in the object listing.

Answer (score 0):

That is probably a bug in the API endpoint which *includes* the "folder" - S3 internally doesn't actually have a folder structure, but instead is just a set of keys associated with files, where keys (for convenience) can contain slash-separated paths which then show up as "folders" in the web interface. There is the option in the API to specify a *prefix*, which I believe can be any part of the key up to and including part of the filename.

Comment: That doesn't explain why it's different on different endpoints. The prefix on both endpoints is the same.

Comment: I did mean it's "probably a bug" as an explanation.

Answer (score 0):

EMR's s3 client is not the apache one, so I can't speak accurately about it.

In ASF hadoop releases (and HDP, CDH)

1. The older [s3n:// client](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3native/NativeS3FileSystem.java#L578) uses `$folder$` as its folder delimiter.
2. The newer [s3a:// client](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/branch-2.7/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/S3AFileSystem.java#L1119) uses / as its folder marker, but will handle $folder$ if there. At least it used to; I can't see where in the code it does now.

The S3A clients strip out all folder markers when you list things; S3A uses them to simulate empty dirs and deletes all parent markers when you create child file/dir entries.

Whatever you have which processes GET should just ignore entries with "/" or $folder at the end.

As to why they are different, the local EMRFS is a different codepath, using dynamo for implementing consistency. At a guess, it doesn't need to mock empty dirs, as the DDB tables will host all directory entries.

Comment: I'm using the same (current) AWS S3 client in both cases.

Comment: if you are using the AWS Java SDK, you get the listing of all blobs. In the Apache S3A client, we 
[strip out the folder markers](https://github.com/apache/hadoop/blob/trunk/hadoop-tools/hadoop-aws/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/fs/s3a/Listing.java#L475). The Amazon EMR S3 client, which you get in an EMR cluster, uses the AWS SDK, and presumably it also filters.

Comment: I'm not using the Java SDK. In my original question, I said I see the same behavior with Amazon's own S3 command-line client.

Comment: we are going round in circles. If the command line client is showing the $folder$, something is creating them, probably amazon's s3 client, maybe something else of theirs. Ignore them